# Does jQuery have any utility that can take an array of property values and map them to a json object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Good Morning,
I'm trying to create an array of javascript objects from a bunch of arrays.  I want each object to look like this. but take the array elements as properties.

```
{
'Miles':0
, 'Drain flush and refill cooling system' : false
, 'Lubricate chassis':false
, 'Replace automatic transaxle fluid and filter':false
, 'Replace engine air cleaner filter':false
, 'Replace engine oil':false
, 'Replace engine oil filter':false
, 'Replace spark plugs':false
, 'Rotate tires':false
, 'Inspect brake system':false
, 'Inspect drive axle boots':false
, 'Inspect engine accessory drive belt':false
, 'Inspect engine air cleaner filter':false
, 'Inspect engine cooling system hoses and clamps':false
, 'Inspect exhaust system':false
, 'Inspect fuel system':false
, 'Inspect spark plug wires':false
, 'Inspect steering system':false
, 'Inspect suspension system':false
, 'Inspect throttle system':false 
}
```

I have an array of values I would like to use to set those property values.  Something similiar to jQuery extend. To override the defaults with new values, except take an array instead of a hash.  Example

```
    [7500,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true].
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  I have 50 arrays like this or I would just type out the objects. I'm trying to save a little time by doing some type of loop and creating an array of objects. Ultimately the array of objects will drive an HTML table on a web page.  I appreciate any tips or tricks to accomplish this.

Cheers,
~ck in San Diego

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about: http://jsfiddle.net/vUg66/

```
function CarSpecs(arr) {
  for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    this[ this.arrayMap[i] ] = arr[i];
  }
}

/** Array specifying the location of each key in the input array */
CarSpecs.prototype.arrayMap = [
  'Miles',
  'Drain flush and refill cooling system',
  'Lubricate chassis',
  'Replace automatic transaxle fluid and filter',
  'Replace engine air cleaner filter',
  'Replace engine oil',
  'Replace engine oil filter',
  'Replace spark plugs',
  'Rotate tires',
  'Inspect brake system',
  'Inspect drive axle boots',
  'Inspect engine accessory drive belt',
  'Inspect engine air cleaner filter',
  'Inspect engine cooling system hoses and clamps',
  'Inspect exhaust system',
  'Inspect fuel system',
  'Inspect spark plug wires',
  'Inspect steering system',
  'Inspect suspension system',
  'Inspect throttle system'
];


var input = [7500,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true];

console.log(new CarSpecs(input));
```

You don't need a CarSpecs object and you could just implement a function that converts the array to an object, I think the CarSpecs constructor is sexier though.

```
function carArrayToObj(array) {
  var arrayMap =  [
      'Miles',
      'Drain flush and refill cooling system',
      'Lubricate chassis',
      'Replace automatic transaxle fluid and filter',
      'Replace engine air cleaner filter',
      'Replace engine oil',
      'Replace engine oil filter',
      'Replace spark plugs',
      'Rotate tires',
      'Inspect brake system',
      'Inspect drive axle boots',
      'Inspect engine accessory drive belt',
      'Inspect engine air cleaner filter',
      'Inspect engine cooling system hoses and clamps',
      'Inspect exhaust system',
      'Inspect fuel system',
      'Inspect spark plug wires',
      'Inspect steering system',
      'Inspect suspension system',
      'Inspect throttle system'
    ];
  var obj = {};
  for (var i=0; i<array.length) {
    obj[arrayMap[i]] = array[i];
  }
  return obj;
}
```

**Here's what I think you should have done**

```
var intervals =[[7500,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true], [15000,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true], [22500,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true], [30000,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,false,true,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true], [37500,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true], [45000,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true], [52500,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true], [60000,false,true,true,true,true,false,false,true,false,true,true,true,true,true,true,false,false,true,true], [67500,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true], [75000,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true], [82500,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true], [90000,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true], [97500,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true], [100000,true,true,false,true,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true], [105000,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true], [112500,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,false,true,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true], [120000,false,true,true,true,true,false,false,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true], [127500,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true], [135000,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,false,true,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true], [142500,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true], [150000,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true]];

function createColumnArray(intervals) {
  var intervalSpecs = [];

  $.each(intervals, function(idx, arr){
    intervalSpecs.push(new CarSpec(arr))
  });
  return intervalSpecs;
}
```

Cheers from SD too!

Answer (score 0):

Associative arrays don't order keys, it's should be safer to update your original array with another associative array.

You can update it easily with a simple loop:

```
for (var i in new_array)
    old_array[i] = new_array[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any jQuery build-in functionality for that case, but it should not be too hard to accomplish:

```
var arr = [];
$.each(yourobject, function(index, elem) {
    arr.push(elem);
});

JSON.stringify(arr);
```

Comment: what is JSON.parse for? JSON.parse takes a string and makes it into an object. Did you mean JSON.stringify just to show output? Besides, this is not turning the array into an object as the OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this.  I haven't tested it, but this should do it. I was hoping jQuery had a shortcut method for this.

```
function createColumnArray(){

var intervals = [
    [7500,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true]
    , [15000,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true]
    , [22500,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true]
    , [30000,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,false,true,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true]
    , [37500,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true]
    , [45000,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true]
    , [52500,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true]
    , [60000,false,true,true,true,true,false,false,true,false,true,true,true,true,true,true,false,false,true,true]
    , [67500,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true]
    , [75000,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true]
    , [82500,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true]
    , [90000,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true]
    , [97500,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true]
    , [100000,true,true,false,true,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true]
    , [105000,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true]
    , [112500,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,false,true,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true]
    , [120000,false,true,true,true,true,false,false,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true]
    , [127500,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true]
    , [135000,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,false,true,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true]
    , [142500,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true]
    , [150000,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true]
];

var oIntervals = [];

$.each(intervals, function(idx, elem){
    oIntervals.push(createInterval(elem));
});

return oIntervals;

}

function createInterval(props){
if(props.length == 20){
    return {
        'Miles': props[0]
        , 'Drain flush and refill cooling system' : props[1]
        , 'Lubricate chassis':props[2]
        , 'Replace automatic transaxle fluid and filter':props[3]
        , 'Replace engine air cleaner filter':props[4]
        , 'Replace engine oil':props[5]
        , 'Replace engine oil filter':props[6]
        , 'Replace spark plugs':props[7]
        , 'Rotate tires':props[8]
        , 'Inspect brake system':props[9]
        , 'Inspect drive axle boots':props[10]
        , 'Inspect engine accessory drive belt':props[11]
        , 'Inspect engine air cleaner filter':props[12]
        , 'Inspect engine cooling system hoses and clamps':props[13]
        , 'Inspect exhaust system':props[14]
        , 'Inspect fuel system':props[15]
        , 'Inspect spark plug wires':props[16]
        , 'Inspect steering system':props[17]
        , 'Inspect suspension system':props[18]
        , 'Inspect throttle system':props[19] 
    }
} 
return null;

}
```

Comment: Why are you using this instead of the solution I proposed? This hardcodes stuff that doesn't need to be hardcoded (the indexes into the array).

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party here, but I'd like to make a different suggestion.

Since you said that this transformation is eventually intended to fuel the rendering of an HTML table, I'd suggest skipping this step entirely.  Instead, use a templating engine like jQuery Templates to correctly render the array in a single step.

For example, given this array of data:

```
var data = {
  values: [7500, false, true, false, true, true, false, false, true, false, false, true, true, true, true, true, false, true, true, true]
};
```

You could use a jQuery Templates definition like this:

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="template">
 <tr>
  <td>Miles</td>
  <td>${values[0]}</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Drain flush and refill cooling system</td>
  <td>${values[1]}</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Lubricate chassis</td>
  <td>${values[2]}</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Replace automatic transaxle fluid and filter</td>
  <td>${values[3]}</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Replace engine air cleaner filter</td>
  <td>${values[4]}</td>
 </tr>
 <!-- Etc... -->
</script>
```

To render the array as a table and inject it into an empty container table with an id of `displayTable`, by using this JavaScript (assuming jQuery and jQuery-tmpl are already included):

```
$('#template').tmpl(data).appendTo('#displayTable');
```

Working demo here, with an improvement in the boolean rendering too: http://jsfiddle.net/bJfvh/